# stat_summary_bin at x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

How do I make ggplot's `stat_summary_bin` do the summaries at specified x-axis values? For example, in the plot below I'd like the summaries at x=-1, 0, 1, 2, etc. Now it's at -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, and 1.5.

```
df = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
stat_summary_bin(binwidth=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe define the `breaks`? Like `breaks = seq(-4.5, 4.5, 1)` or something.

Comment: @aosmith Where? `stat_summary_bin` does not have an argument `break` and it does not care about `scale_x_continuous(breaks=-10:10)`

Comment: There is a `breaks` argument in `stat_summary_bin` in the version of ggplot2 I'm using (ggplot2_2.2.1.9000).  It's explained in the documentation.

Comment: @aosmith The breaks option was only added to the development version of ggplot2 on [July 28, 2017.](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2223) It seems you're running bleeding-edge code, which is fine, but most people use the packages that are on CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in ggplot2 that was only fixed in [late July](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2214). A workaround, from the bug report:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))
ggplot(df, aes(x = cut_width(x, 1, center = 0), y = y)) +
  stat_summary_bin(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

And, to fix the x axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = cut_width(x, 1, center = 0), y = y)) +
  stat_summary_bin(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = -3:3, name = 'x')
```

[image]

The `breaks` argument will be available in the next version of ggplot2, which should be released within the next few weeks.

If you want to run the development version of ggplot2 now, you should be able to do so via:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```